# django - authenticate users using django.test.Client

Tags: python, django

In my tests, I am trying to create and authenticate a User but when I hit my views, it still returns 302

```
def test_Home(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.user = User.objects.create_user("xoxo", password="bar", is_staff=True)
    self.logged_in = self.client.login(
        username="xoxo", password="bar")
    r = self.client.get('/hudson/')
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, HTTP_200_OK)
```

My `/hudson/` view is simply:

```
class HomeView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'foo/base.html'
    permission_required = ('user.is_staff', )
    login_url = reverse_lazy('admin:login')
```

I am getting 302 to my `admin/login` as define in the view.

Comment: Congrats, your test found a bug!

Comment: In Django? :smile: 
In my code? :frown:

Answer (score 3):

`is_staff` is an attribute on the `user` instance, not a permission. You are redirected because the user does not have a permission `'user.is_staff'`.

You could use the [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) mixin instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class HomeView(UserPassesTestMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff 

    template_name = 'foo/base.html'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('admin:login')
```

If you do this in multiple views, you can create your own mixin.

```
class UserIsStaffMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff 

    login_url = reverse_lazy('admin:login')

class HomeView(UserIsStaffMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'foo/base.html'
```

Comment: you mean I will have to change my views to accommodate for the tests? I am using this template for all my views, adding the test_func in each seems stupid. Is there not a better way?

Comment: It's not about accommodating the tests, it's about fixing the views. There is no permission `user.is_staff` (unless you have created it manually), so you cannot use `PermissionRequiredMixin` to check for it.. If you don't want to define the same `test_func` in multiple views, then create your own mixin.